# How to Select Vertices In the position of an active selection?

Tags: scripting

So this class is supposed to select the verts of an active object that is inside of another object but it only works at position near 0,0,0.

```
class ComplexSplitcheck(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "split.check"
bl_label = "Split Check"
bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
bl_description = ""

max_dist = 1.84467e+19

def execute(self, context):
    selected = bpy.context.selected_objects 
    active = bpy.context.active_object
    selected.remove(active)


    for obj in selected:
        for v in active.data.vertices: 
            if is_inside((active.matrix_world * v.co), self.max_dist, obj):             
                v.select = True

    return {'FINISHED'}

def is_inside(p, max_dist, obj):
result, point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, max_dist)
p2 = point-p
v = p2.dot(normal)
return not(v < 0.0)
```

Comment: I expect `closest_point_on_mesh` is only intended to be used on it's own mesh data, try converting the global point to a point local to the target data.